# RecyclerListview item text wrapping

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

This is my recycler listview item.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:padding="5dp"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:weightSum="6">

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:src="@drawable/brandicon"
    android:layout_weight="1" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/brandtext"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="left|center"
    android:paddingRight="5dp"
    android:paddingLeft="5dp"
    android:layout_weight="4"
    android:text="asdasd" />
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/icon"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:src="@drawable/next"
    android:layout_weight="1" />


</LinearLayout>
```

However, when I inflate it in onCreateViewHolder(), the text in the list item is getting wrapped up.
[image]

Comment: What do you mean it is getting wrapped up? You just mean that it isn't showing? It seems like you are populating your list and setting the text of each item to "Item" + number of items

Comment: I mean the right arrow should be at the end. Textview is wrapping up to the text and not occupying the layout_weight that I specified in the TextView tag

Answer (score 0):

This how it works

1. remove android:weightSum="6" from  your LinearLayout
2. remove android:layout_weigh from both ImageViews
3. in the TextView put android:layout_weight="1"

Answer (score -1):

give your RecyclerView a width of match_parent

Comment: Given the same in the fragment layout for the recyclerview

Comment: post your recycler xml

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/iemslist"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
    </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>

</LinearLayout>